# Job related Commission

Tags: fiqh, work

assalamu alaikum, I am working in Saudi Arabia with one of the company's Marketing Department. I have a question related commission. Last week we received one service request from one company (they are not our customers may be in future), they requested for that services in which our company is not dealing, So for them I take that services from the 3rd party, so the 3rd Party gave me 900 Riyals per day & I gave 1000 Riyal per day to my company, and my company gave to client on 1300 Riyal per day.
So my question is this 100 Riyal is Halal or Haram for me.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you are making the contract/deal with your company.

Lets see few scenarios,

1-If you say that third party is taking 1000 riyal per day then its completely Haram,

2-If you are making the contract with your company for 1000 riyals, irrespective of from where your taking the support and irrespective of how you are doing the things then its permissible as its one kind of business.

and many others..